# Optimise a step function in Pandas using data

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, linear-algebra, scipy-optimize

I have two dataframes (df_1 & df_2) and some variables (A,B,C):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,2,3], 'M' : [2,8,3]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],
                     'M' : [9,2,4, 6,7,8, 5,3,4],
                     'X' : [2,4,6, 4,8,7, 3,1,9],
                     'Y' : [3,6,1, 4,6,5, 1,0,7],
                     'Z' : [2,4,8, 3,5,4, 7,5,1]})
```

I have an algorithm, below, that uses A,B,C to calculate a score (S) for each row in df_2. It finds the row in df_2 with the highest score (S). It compares the highest scoring row in df_2 with df_1 and calculates p_hat, a measure of the similarity between them:

```
M_G = df_1.M
df_1 = df_1.set_index('O')
        
A = 1
B = 1
C = 1
 
# Score
df_2['S'] = df_2['X']*A + df_2['Y']*B + df_2['Z']*C
        
# Top score
df_Sort = df_2.sort_values(['S', 'X', 'M'], ascending=[False, True, True])
df_O    = df_Sort.set_index('O')
M_Top   = df_O[~df_O.index.duplicated(keep='first')].M
M_Top   = M_Top.sort_index()
        
# Compare the top scoring row for each O to df_1
df_1_M = df_1.M
df_1_M = df_1_M.sort_index()
df_1_R = df_1_M.reindex(M_Top.index)
T_N_T  = M_Top == df_1_R

# Record the results for the given values of A,B,C
df_Res = pd.DataFrame({'it_is':T_N_T}) # is this row of df_1 the same as this row of M_Top?
        
# p_hat =         TP / (TP + FP)
p_hat = df_Res.sum() / len(df_Res.index)
```

For the values of A,B,C in the example, it gives p_hat = 0.333. I would like to find the values of A,B,C that give the maximum possible value of p_hat. I would like to use an optimisation algorithm to make sure that I get the maximum value please.

The graph is for C=2:

[image]
How can I find the maximum p_hat please?

Comment: If we call columns X,Y,Z 'dimensions' then I'm looking for a solution that would work in many dimensions please.

Comment: I suspect that a solution may require a multi level neural network and that it soesn't need linprog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it using global, brute force optimisation:

```
from scipy.optimize import brute

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,2,3], 'M' : [2,8,3]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],
                     'M' : [9,2,4, 6,7,8, 5,3,4],
                     'X' : [2,4,6, 4,8,7, 3,1,9],
                     'Y' : [3,6,1, 4,6,5, 1,0,7],
                     'Z' : [2,4,8, 3,5,4, 7,5,1]})



# Range
min_ = -2
max_ = 2
step = .5
ran_ge = slice(min_, max_+step, step)
ranges = (ran_ge,ran_ge,ran_ge)

# Params
params = (df_1, df_2)

# Index
df_1 = df_1.set_index('O')
df_1_M = df_1.M
df_1_M = df_1_M.sort_index()

# Fun
def fun(z, *params):
    A,B,C = z
        
    # Score
    df_2['S'] = df_2['X']*A + df_2['Y']*B + df_2['Z']*C
    
    # Top score
    df_Sort = df_2.sort_values(['S', 'X', 'M'], ascending=[False, True, True])
    df_O    = df_Sort.set_index('O')
    M_Top   = df_O[~df_O.index.duplicated(keep='first')].M
    M_Top   = M_Top.sort_index()
        
    # Compare the top scoring row for each O to df_1
    df_1_R = df_1_M.reindex(M_Top.index) # Nan
    T_N_T  = M_Top == df_1_R

    # Record the results for the given values of A,B,C
    df_Res = pd.DataFrame({'it_is':T_N_T}) # is this row of df_1 the same as this row of M_Top?
        
    # p_hat =         TP / (TP + FP)
    p_hat = df_Res.sum() / len(df_Res.index)
    
    return -p_hat

# Brute
resbrute = brute(fun,
                 ranges,
                 args=params,
                 full_output=True,
                 finish=None)

print('Global maximum ',                   resbrute[0])
print('Function value at global maximum ',-resbrute[1])
```

It gives:

```
Global maximum  [-2.   0.5  1.5]
Function value at global maximum  0.6666666666666666
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the Optuna package, it's very easy to use. You define an objective function in which you calculate the variable you want to optimize in which ever way you want, create a `study` object for it and Optuna basically does the rest.

Small example for an easy 2D-function:

```
import optuna

def optimize_me(trial):
    x = trial.suggest_uniform('x', -10, 10)
    y = trial.suggest_uniform('y', -10, 10)
    return ((y - 1) ** 2) + ((x + 2) ** 2)

study = optuna.create_study()
study.optimize(optimize_me, n_trials = 10)
```

You can read more about Optuna [here](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

I use this mainly to optimize hyper parameters for RNNs, it's a very capable package.

Comment: thanks but I think this is optimising a function but I don't have a function, I have data

Comment: You said you want to maximize p_hat which is a measure of similarity and dependent on your dataframe data and A, B, and C. This means you must have some sort of function calculating p_hat. Namely, you could put your `for F_2 in L_2:` loop in the function to optimize

Answer (score 0):

Or using global, evolutionary optimisation: (code fixed by @Aviv Yaniv)

```
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,2,3], 'M' : [2,8,3]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'O' : [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3],
                     'M' : [9,2,4, 6,7,8, 5,3,4],
                     'X' : [2,4,6, 4,8,7, 3,1,9],
                     'Y' : [3,6,1, 4,6,5, 1,0,7],
                     'Z' : [2,4,8, 3,5,4, 7,5,1]})

# Index
df_1 = df_1.set_index('O')
df_1_M = df_1.M
df_1_M = df_1_M.sort_index()

# Fun
def fun(z, *params):
    A,B,C = z
        
    # Score
    df_2['S'] = df_2['X']*A + df_2['Y']*B + df_2['Z']*C
    
    # Top score
    df_Sort = df_2.sort_values(['S', 'X', 'M'], ascending=[False, True, True])
    df_O    = df_Sort.set_index('O')
    M_Top   = df_O[~df_O.index.duplicated(keep='first')].M
    M_Top   = M_Top.sort_index()
        
    # Compare the top scoring row for each O to df_1
    df_1_R = df_1_M.reindex(M_Top.index) # Nan
    T_N_T  = M_Top == df_1_R

    # Record the results for the given values of A,B,C
    df_Res = pd.DataFrame({'it_is':T_N_T}) # is this row of df_1 the same as this row of M_Top?
        
    # p_hat =         TP / (TP + FP)
    p_hat = df_Res.sum() / len(df_Res.index)
    
    print(z)
    return -p_hat[0]

# Bounds
min_ = -2
max_ = 2
ran_ge = (min_, max_)
bounds = [ran_ge,ran_ge,ran_ge]

# Params
params = (df_1, df_2)

# DE
DE = differential_evolution(fun, bounds, args=params)

print('Function value at global maximum ',-DE.fun)
```